# What's the Meaning of the Notation $ \langle \mathbf{\cdot} , \mathbf{\cdot} \rangle$ in $\lambda$-Calculus?

Tags: notation, lambda-calculus

I'm learning $\lambda$-calculus from this book: *Lectures on the Curry-Howard Isomorphism* (1998 version) (https://disi.unitn.it/~bernardi/RSISE11/Papers/curry-howard.pdf), and in page 17, definition 1.5.21 the symbol $ \langle \mathbf{\cdot} , \mathbf{\cdot} \rangle$ appears. I'm not familiar with this symbol, what does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the definition states, it denotes an arbitrary "[bijective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection), [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-recursive_function) function" from $\Bbb N^2$ to $\Bbb N$. In terms of $\langle\bullet,\,\bullet\rangle$, it defines a map $\#$. You may want to see, for example, what this does for the [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function).

Comment: Thanks. When I think of it now, this question is a bit stupid. I'm just not used to this notation, and I saw that it has some use in linear algebra, so I was confused.

Comment: @MichaelNovak You're probably used to functions being written as something like $f(m,\,n)$. The author probably avoided this because the lambda calculus is all about using anonymous functions.

Answer (score 3):

It is an internal notation which is precisely *defined* on the page you refer to:

> Let $\left< \cdot,\cdot \right>:\Bbb N^2\to \Bbb N$ be a bijective, recursive function.

The word *recursive* in this context is defined on page $15$, Def. 1.5.15.